# How are answers with no votes sorted?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, votes

When I was viewing a question: [How can I introduce (or name) a person](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/186852/how-can-i-introduce-or-name-a-person) my answer was above the other answer even though they both have 0 votes. I sorted it by votes.

My answer is above the other answer, but that was only after I reloaded the page. Before, the other answer was hove mine. So I was wondering if there are no votes on any answers or an equal amount of votes and no accepts what are the answers sorted by.

Example:

[image: example]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answers with equal scores are randomly sorted according to [How are answers with the same vote score sorted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107096/273494)?

Accepted answers are at the top, unless the author of the question accepted their own answer.